# Why i got empty Display with my pager in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'am working with jetpack compose, i was created Horizontal Pager with foundation accompanist libary from google.

so i faced a problem that my display shown empty Horizontal pager, and why ?
I have debug and looked at result data in debug mode and  show a lot off data.

[image]

**My Pager Composable**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun AutomaticSliderWithIndicator(
    pagerState: PagerState,
    listBanner: List<Banner>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Box {
        HorizontalPager(
            pageCount = listBanner.size,
            state = pagerState,
        ) {
            AutomaticBannerItem(
                item = Banner(
                    text = listBanner[it].text,
                    qty = listBanner[it].qty,
                    icon = listBanner[it].icon
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**My Screen**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun DashboardScreenDev(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: DashboardViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val state by viewModel.dashboardState.collectAsState()

    val banner = DashboardSlider1.getData()
    val pagerstate = rememberPagerState()
    val datastore = DataStoreRepository(context = LocalContext.current)
    val username = datastore.getUsername().collectAsState(initial = "").value
    val company = datastore.getUserCompany().collectAsState(initial = "").value

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(vertical = 20.dp)
            .padding(AppTheme.dimens.small)
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        TopSectionDashboard(name = username, company = company)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(AppTheme.dimens.mediumLarge))
        state.dashboard?.let { AutomaticSliderWithIndicator(pagerState = pagerstate, listBanner = it.banners) }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try providing ```Modifier``` with proper height and width to the Box, Pager, and Items as well.